# Thread safety in Swift

Tags: ios, thread-safety, swift, atomic

I'm working on a project to handle state machine changes that need to be obeyed between numerous thread but just stumbled onto they are nonatomic by default.
Is there a way to make Swift properties thread-safe or atomic at the time of Xcode6-Beta4?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24157834/are-swift-variables-atomic

Comment: I did read that post but wanted to make sure since the answers written were of a previous Beta. Thanks

Comment: Since Apple hasn't released any "real" documentation right now, the whole Swift paradigm is to be seen as a beta. You can use `objc_sync_enter(self)
//synchronized code
objc_sync_exit(self)` to synchronize your code right now though.

Comment: Properties being atomic is virtually never enough to make code actually thread safe, so I would be surprised if Apple adds atomic properties.

Answer (score 2):

I think [Alexander W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1108547/alexander-w) has the right idea, but I would advise synchronizing on `self` as a general rule.  Perhaps the suggestion I posted here may help:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/28976644/2317256

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your Getters Setters on thread-safe properties with use of dispatch_semaphore_t, NSLock or pthread_mutex_t, or similiar stuff.

Currently, there are no attributes, which define some behaviour, like atomic/nonatomic quialifers of Obj-C