# Are reference types in Swift atomic or nonatomic?

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, properties, atomic

In `Objective-C`, you could declare a property to be either `atomic` or `nonatomic`, being `atomic` the default value. In `Swift`, those keywords have disappeared and I didn't find any information regarding that in the [Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/) guide, so I'm not sure if properties in `Swift` keep being `atomic` by default or not, or if there is another new way to define `atomic` or `nonatomic`.

I've read in [this post](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/25642) that now by default properties are `nonatomic`, but no source provided.

Comment: you can see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24157834/are-swift-variables-atomic